# my android application works good on my emulator but in the device is crashed

Tags: android, crash, ondraw, invalidation

When I run my application in the emulator it works well, but in my device it crashed.

When I open my activity and call the `ondraw` method
I figured that the `Invalidate();` is the problem:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    getinfoGFX.open();

    String d = "";
    semesterNo = getinfoGFX.getDataSemestersNo(s);
    semestrYear = getinfoGFX.getDataSemestersYear(s);
    semestrId = getinfoGFX.getDataSemestersID(s);

    LastGPA = getinfoGFX.getDataLastGPA(s);
    LastHourse = getinfoGFX.getDataLastHourse(s);
    Type = getinfoGFX.getGPAType(s);

    subAllGrades = getinfoGFX.getdataAllSubjectsGrades(semestrId);
    subAllHourse = getinfoGFX.getdataAllSubjectsHourse(semestrId);

    pText1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    pText1.setTextSize(35);
    pText1.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    pText1.setTypeface(font);
    pText1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    pText1.setStrokeWidth(5);

    pText2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    pText2.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    pText2.setTypeface(font);
    pText2.setTextSize(35);
    pText2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pText2.setStrokeWidth(0);

    pText3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    pText3.setTextSize(35);
    pText3.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    pText3.setTypeface(font);
    pText3.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    pText3.setStrokeWidth(5);

    pText4.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    pText4.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    pText4.setTypeface(font);
    pText4.setTextSize(35);
    pText4.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pText4.setStrokeWidth(0);

    rect1.setColor(Color.rgb(79, 129, 189));
    rect1.setStrokeWidth(0);
    rect1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    rect2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    rect2.setStrokeWidth(0);
    rect2.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    int count = 0;

    canvas.drawColor(Color.alpha(0));
    dy-=10;
    canvas.translate(0, dy);
    for (int i = 0; i < semesterNo.length; i++) {
        float height = (getMeasuredHeight() / 8);
        float startY = (getMeasuredHeight() / 8) * count;
        float semYearStartX = getMeasuredWidth() / 4, semYearStartY = startY, semYearEndX = semYearStartX
                + semYearStartX + semYearStartX, semYearEndY = semYearStartY
                + height;
        float semNoStartX = 0, semNoStartY = semYearEndY, semNoEndX = getMeasuredWidth(), semNoEndY = semNoStartY
                + height;
        float GradeStartX = 0, GradeStartY = semNoEndY, GradeEndX = getMeasuredWidth() / 4, GradeEndY = GradeStartY
                + height;
        float HourseStartX = GradeEndX, HourseStartY = semNoEndY, HourseEndX = getMeasuredWidth() / 2, HourseEndY = GradeStartY
                + height;
        float SubNameStartX = HourseEndX, SubNameStartY = semNoEndY, SubNameEndX = getMeasuredWidth(), SubNameEndY = GradeStartY
                + height;

        canvas.drawRect(GradeStartX, GradeStartY, GradeEndX, GradeEndY,
                rect2);
        canvas.drawRect(GradeStartX + 3, GradeStartY + 3, GradeEndX - 3,
                GradeEndY - 3, rect1);
        canvas.drawRect(HourseStartX, HourseStartY, HourseEndX, HourseEndY,
                rect2);
        canvas.drawRect(HourseStartX + 3, HourseStartY + 3, HourseEndX - 3,
                HourseEndY - 3, rect1);
        canvas.drawRect(SubNameStartX, SubNameStartY, SubNameEndX,
                SubNameEndY, rect2);
        canvas.drawRect(SubNameStartX + 3, SubNameStartY + 3,
                SubNameEndX - 3, SubNameEndY - 3, rect1);
        canvas.drawRect(semNoStartX, semNoStartY, semNoEndX, semNoEndY,
                rect2);
        canvas.drawRect(semNoStartX + 3, semNoStartY + 3, semNoEndX - 3,
                semNoEndY - 3, rect1);
        canvas.drawRect(semYearStartX, semYearStartY, semYearEndX,
                semYearEndY, rect2);
        canvas.drawRect(semYearStartX + 3, semYearStartY + 3,
                semYearEndX - 3, semYearEndY - 3, rect1);


        canvas.drawText("السنة رقم" + semestrYear[i],
                (semYearEndX + semYearStartX) / 2,
                (semYearEndY + semYearStartY) / 2, pText1);
        canvas.drawText("السنة رقم" + semestrYear[i],
                (semYearEndX + semYearStartX) / 2,
                (semYearEndY + semYearStartY) / 2, pText2);

        canvas.drawText("الفصل الدراسي " + semesterNo[i], semNoEndX,
                (semNoStartY + semNoEndY) / 2, pText3);
        canvas.drawText("الفصل الدراسي " + semesterNo[i], semNoEndX,
                (semNoStartY + semNoEndY) / 2, pText4);

        canvas.drawText("الدرجة", (GradeStartX + GradeEndX) / 2,
                (GradeStartY + GradeEndY) / 2 + 15, pText1);
        canvas.drawText("الدرجة", (GradeStartX + GradeEndX) / 2,
                (GradeStartY + GradeEndY) / 2 + 15, pText2);

        canvas.drawText("الساعات", (HourseEndX + HourseStartX) / 2,
                (HourseEndY + HourseStartY) / 2 + 15, pText1);
        canvas.drawText("الساعات", (HourseEndX + HourseStartX) / 2,
                (HourseEndY + HourseStartY) / 2 + 15, pText2);

        canvas.drawText("اسم المادة", (SubNameEndX + SubNameStartX) / 2,
                (SubNameEndY + SubNameStartY) / 2 + 15, pText1);
        canvas.drawText("اسم المادة", (SubNameEndX + SubNameStartX) / 2,
                (SubNameEndY + SubNameStartY) / 2 + 15, pText2);
        subjectsId = getinfoGFX.getdataSubjectsID(semestrId[i]);
        semesterF = getinfoGFX.getdataSemesterIdF(semestrId[i]);
        subName = getinfoGFX.getdataSubjectsName(semestrId[i]);
        subHourse = getinfoGFX.getdataSubjectsHourse(semestrId[i]);
        subGrades = getinfoGFX.getdataSubjectsGrades(semestrId[i]);
        count++;
        for (int k = 0; k < subName.length; k++) {


            startY = (getMeasuredHeight() / 8) * count;
            semYearStartX = getMeasuredWidth() / 4;
            semYearStartY = startY;
            semYearEndX = semYearStartX + semYearStartX + semYearStartX;
            semYearEndY = semYearStartY + height;
            semNoStartX = 0; 
            semNoStartY = semYearEndY;
            semNoEndX = getMeasuredWidth();
            semNoEndY = semNoStartY+ height;
            GradeStartX = 0;
            GradeStartY = semNoEndY;
            GradeEndX = getMeasuredWidth() / 4;
            GradeEndY = GradeStartY+ height;
            HourseStartX = GradeEndX;
            HourseStartY = semNoEndY; 
            HourseEndX = getMeasuredWidth() / 2; 
            HourseEndY = GradeStartY + height;
            SubNameStartX = HourseEndX;
            SubNameStartY = semNoEndY;
            SubNameEndX = getMeasuredWidth();
            SubNameEndY = GradeStartY+ height;

            canvas.drawRect(GradeStartX, GradeStartY, GradeEndX, GradeEndY,
                    rect2);
            canvas.drawRect(GradeStartX + 3, GradeStartY + 3, GradeEndX - 3,
                    GradeEndY - 3, rect1);
            canvas.drawRect(HourseStartX, HourseStartY, HourseEndX, HourseEndY,
                    rect2);
            canvas.drawRect(HourseStartX + 3, HourseStartY + 3, HourseEndX - 3,
                    HourseEndY - 3, rect1);
            canvas.drawRect(SubNameStartX, SubNameStartY, SubNameEndX,
                    SubNameEndY, rect2);
            canvas.drawRect(SubNameStartX + 3, SubNameStartY + 3,
                    SubNameEndX - 3, SubNameEndY - 3, rect1);

            canvas.drawText(subGrades[k], (GradeStartX + GradeEndX) / 2,
                    (GradeStartY + GradeEndY) / 2 + 15, pText1);
            canvas.drawText(subGrades[k], (GradeStartX + GradeEndX) / 2,
                    (GradeStartY + GradeEndY) / 2 + 15, pText2);

            canvas.drawText(subHourse[k], (HourseEndX + HourseStartX) / 2,
                    (HourseEndY + HourseStartY) / 2 + 15, pText1);
            canvas.drawText(subHourse[k], (HourseEndX + HourseStartX) / 2,
                    (HourseEndY + HourseStartY) / 2 + 15, pText2);

            canvas.drawText(subName[k], (SubNameEndX + SubNameStartX) / 2,
                    (SubNameEndY + SubNameStartY) / 2 + 15, pText1);
            canvas.drawText(subName[k], (SubNameEndX + SubNameStartX) / 2,
                    (SubNameEndY + SubNameStartY) / 2 + 15, pText2);
            count++;
        }
        count+=subName.length+1;

    }
    getinfoGFX.close();
    canvas.drawText(LastGPA, getMeasuredWidth()/2, getMeasuredHeight()/2, pText1);
    canvas.drawText(LastGPA, getMeasuredWidth()/2, getMeasuredHeight()/2, pText2);
    invalidate();

    super.onDraw(canvas);

}
```

When I delete the `invalidate();` line it doesn't crash but I need it in my application.

**UPDATE:** Here is the error log

```
  12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096): android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=752 (# cursors opened by this proc=752)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:108)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:100)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:289)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:196)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:236)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at com.example.gpa.dataBase.getdataSemesterIdF(dataBase.java:453)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at com.example.gpa.semestersGFX.onDraw(semestersGFX.java:162)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13767)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12718)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12762)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12654)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12762)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12654)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12762)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12654)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12762)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12654)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12762)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1144)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2147)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1958)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4518)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
12-15 13:25:17.765: E/AndroidRuntime(4096):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could post an error log from logcat of what the crash is.

Comment: my emulator it is run correctly the problem in my device
how i can detect the error log from my device

Comment: connect your device with your system. make sure the device drivers are installed. then look for log cat error when application crashes

Comment: Never ever ever create new objects in onDraw. Just draw. Data management should be done elsewhere in the class.

Comment: Have you heard of minimal code to explain your problem ? You cant put all your code in to get a issue understood. You need to reduce it so that its interesting in enuf for people to read. Not more than 10 lines.

Comment: @user1479606 Any reason why think a answer is worthy of a "accept". Isn't the liberty of the owner of the question to decide ? Have you read the FAQ ? You cant beg for reputation +1's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**  Looking at the error log, it looks like your problem is in the `getinfoGFX` class.  In your `getdata...` methods it looks like you are creating a cursor for an SQL query.  Check to make sure you are calling the `close()` method on the cursor prior to exiting.

---

The call to Invalidate() is a problem.  Not sure if it is causing the crash until I see the logs, but you are basically setting it up to continuously redraw.  From the android documentation Invalidate does the following --

> Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible,
>   onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the
>   future. This must be called from a UI thread.

If you call it from inside your onDraw routine as you are doing, you keep the onDraw function always running.